# How to insert in SQLite table after the process is completed in php?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, sqlite

I am working on a php code as shown below which lists all the mp4 files present in a directory.

> Status.php

```
<?php 
$mp4_files = array_values($mp4_files);

print_r($mp4_files);

print_r($mp4_files);  // Line X

foreach ($programs as $key => $program) { 
   $file = $mp4_files[$key];    

   print_r($file);   // Line Y   
   print_r($key);    // Line Z

?>
<tr class="box" data-index="<?php echo $key; ?>">
<td><button  data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary">Go</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

**Line X** prints `Array ( [0] => 36031P.mp4 [1] => hello.mp4 )` 
**Line Y** prints `36031P.mp4 hello.mp4` 
**Line Z** prints `0 and 1`

On hitting Go button, it calls the JS/jQuery code below:

> JS/jQuery:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($)
   {
    $('.converter').click(function()
    {   
        let target = $(this).attr('data-id'),
            spanEl = $('.file-name[data-id='+ target +']');
        let btn = this;
        $(btn).val("Converting").prop('disabled', true);           // Line A
        $.ajax({
            url: 'convert.php',                                   // converts mp4 file into mp3
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: target}, 
            success: function(res)
            {
                 $(btn).val("Completed").prop('disabled', true);  // Line B
            },
        })
    })
   });
```

**Line B** is called in AJAX function when successful **conversion of mp4 into mp3** has happened.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what code I need to add around Line B so that when a **particular mp4 file is converted into mp3** then inside
  the **Podcast_Export** table for a particular mp4 file, Go text should change it into Completed.

[image]

Comment: Instead of $(btn).val( you should use $(btn).html(

Comment: Something like this  `$(btn).html("Completed").prop('disabled', true);` ?

Comment: @jeff are you around ?